# Can a single entity be a non-aggregate?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Lets say I have 3 entities: A, B and C.

- A and B are both aggregate roots and reference C
- C does not reference anything

Does this mean by DDD that C is also an aggregate root because it is referenced by more than one entity? (Or else it could be part of that only referencing entities aggregate).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  In this case C is an entity, and not an aggregate root.